# Is there a way to change the password and auditing policy with a script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, group-policy, auditing, password-policy

I am trying to write a script to change the password and auditing policy on a local machine as one would do through Group Policy editor. However, I have not found a way to change these settings through a batch script, whether by editing the registry or through specific commands (I especially looked into using secedit with `secedit /configure /db secedit.sdb /cfg "TemplateFile.inf"` to create the database and `secedit /refreshpolicy machine_policy /enforce` but was unable to apply the settings to the machine). Unfortunately, the machines I would need to run this on are not in a domain, it would just speed up setting settings on each individual machine.

What could I do to change and apply new password policy and auditing settings via a script?

Comment: Show us the code that you have tried...

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/net-useradmin.html

Comment: @kebs I've tried using `secedit /configure /db secedit.sdb /cfg "TemplateFile.inf"` to create the database and `secedit /refreshpolicy machine_policy /enforce`, but that seems to have no effect. In terms of registry changes, that seems a bit more dicey and I have avoided going too far into it, though, to be honest, I have not really found the specific keys to change regardless.

Comment: @Squashman That seems to be quite effective for my use case. Thank you for your help!